# Developing a Codeigniter game

Tags: php, oop, codeigniter, content-management-system

I have a pretty reasonable amount of experience in PHP (around ~5 years of experience with some websites made and two browser games).  This is the first time I’ve really messed around with a core engine instead of just developing a plugin or module for something like Joomla.  I have an extensive amount of experience in other object oriented languages (such as Java).

My question is, I find myself developing the site much like a normal site, but I want it to be more flexible than that and I’m not sure I’m “doing it right”.  In a way, I feel like I’m building half a CMS.

For example, I have the main page set up through a controller that controls what views are currently being displayed.  The main view page looks like this:

```
<?php $this->load->view("headerview"); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($contentview); ?>
<?php $this->load->view("footerview"); ?>
```

in a view file itself (so I can dynamically load the contentview, the others don’t really change).  This is my first question, since I do ALL the control through my main control file, is this correct?

My index function sets the mainview as the view to be loaded with variables for the “contentview” and “gameview”.  When “contentview” is the game, it has a split pane, one showing the players stats and such, and the other showing whichever page the player is currently on (the merchant shop, in a battle, exploring the world, etc.).  What determines what is being shown here is the “gamecontent” variable (also passed in the “main” controller).

```
<?php $this->load->view("menubar"); ?>
<?php $this->load->view($gamecontent); ?>
```

In short, all view handling is currently being done in the main controller, i.e. one single controller.

```
$data['title'] = "Experimental Page";
$data['maincontent'] = "gameview";
if($page == 1) {
    $data['gamecontent'] = "townview";
} else if ($page == 2) {
    $data['gamecontent'] = "merchantview";
} else if ($page == 3) {
    $data['gamecontent'] = "explorationview";
} else if ($page == 4) {
    $data['gamecontent'] = "hospitalview";
} else if ($page == 5) {
    $data['gamecontent'] = "fightview";
} else if ($page == 6) {
    $data['gamecontent'] = "adminview";
}

$this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->load->view('mainview', $data);
```

I haven’t started adding the fighting and shopping functions yet, but I can see this controller getting very large, very fast.  This seems wrong to me, but somehow I can’t formulate how to properly arrange the core setup.

My goal is to (hopefully) split up the controllers so that each one handles a separate game function, like healing, fighting, exploring and so on, and is separated much like my models are (user, mobs, items, etc.).

Can anyone help me figure out how to properly arrange this project?

Comment: Somewhat irrelevant, but all those conditions can be replaced with a lookup table, i.e. `$table = array("townview", "merchantview", "explorationview", ...); $data['gamecontent'] = $table[$page - 1];` or something along those lines. You could then even separate the game content into its own "config file" and have PHP parse it (and cache it), but that might be overkill if you don't have a lot of data to maintain.

Comment: It's a reasonably small amount of data, I realize I could store the pages in a number of ways, but this is really just to get something done :)

Comment: I developed a game in code igniter (poker, no less) and went down the same path you're finding yourself on. In retrospect, symfony provides a much better architecture for this.

Comment: Unless I misunderstand OP, why not just use multiple controllers? If you're concerned about loading views repeatedly, look in to a template library - http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=code+igniter+template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use the [Symfony Event Dispatcher](http://components.symfony-project.org/event-dispatcher/) component to do something like this; the component can be installed without using the Symfony Framework, so you can use it with CodeIgniter, but there might already be something similar available to you; I don't know CodeIgniter.

The Event Dispatcher is a generic implementation of the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

- I have a list of modules which register themselves as observers for any actions which they handle
- Each request passes through an action (e.g. "townview")
- My controller just creates an Event with whatever the action was as the name; the Event Dispatcher system then finds any modules which claim to be able to handle that action and passes over control to them

This way the main controller doesn't have to change, no matter how many actions you have; it just creates an event and throws it out through the dispatcher; if it's not handled it throws a massive error (in DEV) or a nice one (in PROD).

This is especially useful in our application, where we have lots of optional components that can be switched on or off for different users / clients; no complex logic in the controller at all, I just don't register the modules if they aren't enabled for a client.

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with event dispatching but it sounds a lot like web services, is that correct?  For example, I have a Flash program that calls the AMFPHP server which serves up whatever object's method I called and returns the results, keeping the server side code on one side, and the client side on another.  Similar?  Or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: Well, it *could* be, but in this case it's nothing to do with event dispatching.  The idea is that each module says to a central controller "I can handle event X", then elsewhere in the code you can create event X and ask that something handles it.  It reduces coupling, as the event creator (in this case your controller) doesn't need to know about the things that are actually handling the event (e.g. your different views).  Have a look at the wiki page, then have a read through the event dispatcher docs - they explain things very clearly.